# How to choose a workstation for optimal performance

Tags: julia, cpu-usage, ram

I am looking for some advice on how to choose a workstation. My budget is around $5000.

I simulate structural economic models using Julia. My codes typically use big arrays (through which I iterate using for loops), involve large Monte Carlo simulations, and minimisation algorithms. I parallelise as much as I can.

As I understand it, it would be beneficial for me to have a machine with as many cores as possible and quite a lot of RAM. However, I am not sure how to balance these two. What is the trade-off? Also, does the quality of the cores matter?

Is there anything else that I should take into account apart from RAM and cores/CPU?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is extremely broad. Depending on your requirements, it might make more sense to invest in cluster computing time rather than try to build a powerful workstation. Also, depending what type of calculations you use, consider GPU as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is _very_ off-topic. We are here to answer _concrete programming questions_ and nothing else. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

It depends on wheter your algorithms is parallelizable and if yes, whether it is constrained by memory bandwidth or compute power. Most algorithms are bandwidth-restricted. Large arrays sounds also GPU-) parrallelizable, provided the array components are independent of each other.
Largest performance here offer CPUs with as much memory channels as possible. Normal desktop CPUs usually have 2-channel memory, AMD Threadripper have 4-channel and Threadripper Pro have 8-channel. So a ~24-core Threadripper Pro with 8x8GB /8x16GB memory may be suitable in your budget.

If you parallelize a lot, maybe consider using a GPU. Julia also supports GPU parallelization. When running very parallelizable code, a single GPU can be about as powerful as 2000 CPU cores. The speedup really is substantial. Memory bandwidth for GPUs is also orders of magnitude larger than for CPUs.
The main crux is that GPUs have very limited, non-expandable memory, and GPUs with a lot of memory tend to become disproportunately expensive. If 24GB is enough for your workloads, go for an RTX3090. If you parallelize most of your code on the GPU, the CPU does not matter nearly as much, and you can choose a  normal desktop cpu, for example the 16-core AMD Ryzen 5950X with 4x16GB (2-channel), and stick entirely with consumer / gamer hardware which is much more powerful for much less money.

Comment: [Please don't answer off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/354577)